# spyderlib funny behaviour with any() and all()

Tags: python-2.7, spyder

If I'm on Python 2.7 and I've just started using the Spyder IDE.

On a terminal python version if I do

```
any(i ==1 for i in [1,2,3,4])
```

I get the answer

`True`

While if I do the same in Spyder I get the response

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x3fc8af0>
```

Why is it doing that? Am I missing a setting or might this be a different version of Python (it says 2.7)

Comment: Do you mean the shell in the IDE?

Comment: Hi @Satoru.Logic thanks for looking at this. Yes the first answer response is from the terminal shell. (I'm on linux so if I type `python` at the command prompt in a terminal window).

Comment: I'll try it with my version running under OSX.

Comment: Probably Spyder is importing `numpy.all` into scope.  If you search on SO for `numpy all` or `numpy any` you'll find it explained (`numpy` doesn't play well with generators for various reasons.)

Comment: Thanks @DSM that was the right spot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quote from another [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500388/) about Spyder's Python console behavior:

> One of Spyder's primary design goals is to make interactive scientific
>   computing as painless as possible. To facilitate that, by default
>   Spyder launches a custom-tailored interactive Python session at
>   startup. It achieves this customization by setting an environment
>   variable called PYTHONSTARTUP which specifies the path to a script
>   that will be executed at interpreter startup. You can control this
>   setting under Preferences...Console...Advanced settings. By default,
>   Spyder points to scientific_startup.py, which imports a whole host of
>   scientific modules and functions directly into the main namespace so
>   that quick, interactive exploration is easy.

As a consequence, the behavior you are experiencing is because you are actually calling the `numpy` versions of `any` and `all` which have been placed directly into the main namespace. To verify this, call

```
np.any(i ==1 for i in [1,2,3,4])
```

or

```
np.all(i ==1 for i in [1,2,3,4])
```

in the Spyder Python console, and you'll get the same generator objects being returned. By the way, these last two calls magically work because the startup script also does `import numpy as np`. For more details on what else is imported, type `scientific` at the Spyder Python console prompt.

Comment: thansk @Jed. changing the pythonpath back to default solved the problem.

Comment: @TahnoonPasha, the scientific startup script is only loaded for "interactive" interpreters in Spyder. If you want plain vanilla Python behavior without disabling the scientific startup option, create a script in the editor, hit F6, set the script to "Execute in a new dedicated Python interpreter." If you want to interact with the interpreter after the script completes that can be enabled from that dialog, too. Then run the script.  The interpreter that gets launched in this fashion does not import the scientific startup script even if the scientific startup script option is enabled.